# How to fix a local copy messed up with git reset HASH

Tags: git, version-control, reset

m

I added some changes to a local file and then committed them (A) , I then added more commits (B&C) and then realized, that I didn't want the change from commit (A) so I went ahead and did a `git reset --hard <HASH>`

which removed the previ9ous commit from the `git log` but kept the change I added in (A) in the file and when I change this file now back to its original state, it marks it as  changed which I don't want. I want the file to reflect the `origin`. How do I get this done from here?

(I thought this is what `reset --hard` does)

Comment: If you want your branch X to reflect what the origin (aka remote) thinks it should be, you might just want to execute `git reset --hard origin/X` when you have checked out X. Note that before you experiment further you might want to ensure you have a copy of your repository folder, and possibly even that you experiment on the copy so that you leave the original intact if you mess up.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I want this `git reset --hard origin/X` but only for a single file and keep my other local changes in the branch

Comment: You can't do that with the reset command, `git reset` works on the repository level. You will need something like `git checkout <HASH> -- path/to/file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [already answered in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230509/how-to-fix-a-local-copy-messed-up-with-git-reset-hash#comment120588161_68230509), you can't get the final effect you want with `git reset`.  The details here are, however, quite messy, because `git reset` is something of a [kitchen-sink](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kitchen-sink) command.

> I added some changes to a local file and then committed them (A) ...

The thing to realize here is that every Git commit is a *full snapshot of every file*.  When you change one file and make a new commit, you make a new *full snapshot*.

This doesn't take a whole lot of disk space, because the files that are inside Git commits are not ordinary files.  They're stored in a special, compressed, Git-ified, and *de-duplicated* form.  So new commit `A` simply re-uses all the old files from earlier commit `α`, except for the one modified file, which gets a new snapshot.<sup>1</sup>

> I then added more commits (B&C) and then realized, that I didn't want the change from commit (A) so I went ahead and did a `git reset --hard <HASH>` ...

This kind of `git reset` is about *going to a specific commit*.

Commits, in Git, are laid out a bit like a string of pearls.

Each commit has a unique but random-looking hash ID, which is just a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) encoding of a very large number.  It's impossible to know the hash ID of some commit unless you have all the data *from* the commit, or are simply given the hash ID directly, so the way Git handles this is that each commit *also* stores the hash ID of its immediate predecessor (along with the snapshot, and other metadata).  Git then only needs some way to store the hash ID of the *last* commit in this chain, because each commit points backwards to the previous commit:

```
δ <-γ <-β <-α <-A <-B <-C   <-- your-branch
```

The letters (A, B, and C from your own question, plus some Greek ones in backwards order for earlier commits in the chain) stand in, here, for the random-looking hash IDs.  When you made commit `A` the chain went from:

```
δ <-γ <-β <-α   <-- your-branch
```

to:

```
δ <-γ <-β <-α <-A   <-- your-branch
```

because Git added a *new commit* `A`, holding a full snapshot, plus the hash ID of the previous end of the chain.  Then, when you made commit `B`, you got:

```
δ <-γ <-β <-α <-A <-B   <-- your-branch
```

and so on for commit `C`.

The `git reset` command tells Git: *Stop remembering the current last-commit using the current branch name.  Instead, make this branch name point to the commit I specified.*  Since you specified commit `A`, that gave you:

```
                  B <-C   [no name to find C]
                 /
δ <-γ <-β <-α <-A   <-- your-branch
```

Besides the "move the branch name" action of `git reset`, it also has an effect on Git's index and your working tree, unless you tell it not to.  There are other modes for the `git reset` command that do other things, but let's not wander too far astray; my answers are already too long as is.

If you want your `B` and `C` commits back, they *are* recoverable, for a while.  The main problem with recovering them is finding the hash ID of commit `C`.  (You don't have to find the hash ID of commit `B`, because commit `C` holds that hash ID for you.  You only have to find the *last* commit in the chain: Git will find everything earlier automatically, from there.)

Fortunately, Git has something it calls *reflogs*, where it keeps the hash IDs that *were* stored in some name, for a minimum of 30 days by default.  You can look at the reflog for `HEAD`, or the reflog for your branch name, to find the hash ID of commit `C`.  Use `git reflog` or `git reflog branch` to do this.

Assuming you put these two back (with another `git reset --hard`) so that your strand-of-pearls commits are back to:

```
δ <-γ <-β <-α <-A <-B <-C   <-- your-branch
```

you can now, very easily, add a *new* commit `D` to your branch that simply *undoes* the effect of commit `A` entirely, using `git revert`.  Or, you can create a new commit `D` whose snapshot is the same as that of `C`, except that one particular file's contents are those extracted from any given commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>These individual file snapshots are later further compressed, beyond their initial compression and Git-ization, in what Git calls *pack files*, which means that even multiple versions of large text files don't take much space in the end.  You don't need to care about these details, though: it suffices to remember that each commit acts as a full archive, like a tar or zip or rar archive, of *every* file.

---

#### Using `git revert`

The `git revert` command works by comparing a commit's content to its parent's content.  Whatever *changed* here, that change is to be *un-done* in the *current* set of files by reverse-applying the change, more or less.<sup>2</sup>  So if you modified file *F* in commit `A`, but did nothing to any other file, `git revert hash-of-A` will back out that one change.  Git will make a new commit out of the resulting files.

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, a revert is a three-way merge, with the current commit being the current commit as always, but with the *merge base* being the child commit that you specify on your `git revert` command, and the *other commit* of the three-way merge being the parent of that parent/child pair.

---

#### Using `git restore` or `git checkout`

Every commit has, as already mentioned, a full snapshot of all your files.

To get one particular file *out* of one particular commit, you can use the new (since Git 2.23) `git restore` command:

```
git restore -SW --source <commit> -- <path/to/file>
```

The `-S` and `-W` options, both chosen here, tell `git restore` to write the replacement file to both the staging area (so that you don't have to `git add` the file afterward) *and* your working tree.  The default would be to write to just your working tree, requiring a subsequent `git add`.

The source commit can be a raw hash ID, or you can use any name that will locate the correct hash ID.  If `origin/main` picks a commit that has the correct copy of the file, you can use `--source origin/main`.  You can abbreviate `--source` as `-s` (note lowercase, vs the `-S` uppercase for staging-area).

If your Git predates 2.23, you can use:

```
git checkout <commit> -- <path/to/file>
```

which has the same effect as the `git restore -SW` command (writes to both index / staging-area, and working tree).

In any case, after using these methods, you will need to make one new commit.

#### Using interactive rebase

Instead of *adding a new commit*, it's possible to *replace a whole series of commits* with new and improved substitute commits.  The `git rebase` command is intended for this purpose; when used with `--interactive` (or `-i` for short), `git rebase` is a powerful way to stop using a whole slew of old-and-bad commits.  The old commits are not *gone:* just as with `git reset --hard`, Git still keeps the old commits for a while (at least 30 days by default).  But your Git stops using them, in favor of the new-and-improved commits that `git rebase` builds before abandoning the old commits.

Because this *does* abandon old commits, rebase is not always appropriate.  In particular, if *other* Git repositories have copies of the old commits, it can be very hard to convince *every* Git repository to switch to the new and improved commits instead.  The old, bad commits may keep coming back to haunt you.  Adding a revert commit does not have this problem, since Git is built to *add* commits but not to *drop* old ones (reset and rebase being exceptions that work in *your* repository, but don't affect anyone else's).

Comment: That is an excellent post as for describing the functions and consequences! Thanks a lot torek! Awesome lesson!